# Excel function STEYX to Java

Tags: java, excel

I'm working on a migration of calculations that exist in an excel spreadsheet for java, but I'm having difficulty in the function STEYX, has anyone ever had to do this?

> STEYX(data_y, data_x)  Summary Calculates the standard error of the
>   predicted y-value for each x in the regression of a dataset. data_y
>   The range representing the array or matrix of dependent data. data_x
>   The range representing the array or matrix of independent data.

example data:

```
y = 8734,-3943,3294
x= -3243,3434,-1323 
result= 1423.150065
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example of Regression in Java:

[Regression.java](https://github.com/drewdepriest/RegressionTesting/blob/master/src/Regression.java)

Answer (score 0):

The formula is available on the [Office Support website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/STEYX-function-6ce74b2c-449d-4a6e-b9ac-f9cef5ba48ab):

> The equation for the standard error of the predicted y is:
>
> [image]
>
> where x and y are the sample means AVERAGE(known_x’s) and AVERAGE(known_y’s), and n is the sample size.

You might also want to do a web search for [`standard error of predicted`](https://www.google.com/search?q=standard%20error%20of%20predicted) to learn about it.